# How can I make two queries at once in MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb

I have two IDs and two collections:

```
id1 = "otherId", id2="foo"

C1:
{ key: "bob", field: "someId" }

C2:
{ key: "foo", otherField: "bar" }, 
{ key: "foo", otherField: "bob" }
```

What I want to know is if there is any way to insert into `C1` a new document for each entry with `key = foo`in the `C2` collection, but I want to do it in one query, and from PHP. If I was using SQL, and `C1` and `C2` were tables, I'll do it like this:

```
INSERT INTO C1 VALUES (SELECT otherField, 'otherId' FROM C2 WHERE key = 'foo')
```

Maybe it's not possible. In fact, I've searched over SO and it seems that this can't be done in one query.

Thanks

Comment: I know this is not answering your question, but _id must be unique so C2 is not possible as you described

Comment: @ClintonBosch sorry, you are right, as I wrote it, the question must lead to misunderstandings. The fact is I don't care about `_id` mongo values, I have changed the names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While using MongoDB I think the business logic should go into the Application level and not DB. So you select and then create the object and SAVE.

AFAIK, it is not possible.

Since your second table value depends on the first, it would be great if you could create both the objects and in a transaction, from the Application level, then save them in DB. This is exactly what I do in my projects. I think its the changes you have to make switching from SQL to NoSQL.

Comment: The problem is that I need to query the DB to know which `otherField` values I have before constructing the documents that I want to save. It seems that I will have to do two queries.